# How to play a video after iBeacon detection?

Tags: swift, video, ibeacon

I am new in the iBeacon and Swift development and I have some problems with my application. In the following code bellow, I am trying to detect iBeacon and when I detect the minor value of the beacon I attach it to the link I want to play. The problem occurs when I start the program. The video starts playing for a second and then the whole application stops with the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "8492E75F-4FD6-469D-B132-043FE94921D8")!, identifier: "Estimotes")


   let videos = [


    19987: NSURL ( string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"),


                ]



   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon

        if let url = self.videos[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] {


            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as! URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer

        }
        self.present(self.avPlayerViewController,animated: true) { () -> Void in
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Would you please advice me how to fix that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)` **ranging callback gets called every second.**   So your code to present the video player will execute every second.   This might work the first time, but the second time, you'll get an error because the call to `self.present(...)` is trying to present the same view controller that you already presented.  **You can't present the same  view controller over and over again.**

The solution depends on how you want this to work.  Do you just want this presentation to happen once?  If so, you could do:

```
if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
    let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon

    if let url = self.videos[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] {

        // only execute this code once, if avPlayer not created yet
        if self.avPlayer == nil { 
            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as! URL)
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
            self.present(self.avPlayerViewController,animated: true) { () -> Void in
                self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really solved my problem. I will keep that in mind next time and I really learned something new. Vote Up from me :)

Comment: Hey Would you please tell me how to display the video when the app is closed. I added the  Privacy - Location Always Usage Description , but still it doesn't work