# How to show a notification to the users after detecting iBeacon, while the app is running and while it is closed?

Tags: swift, notifications, ibeacon

In my swift 3 Application, I have 2 iBeacons which should perform different tasks. One of them should open and play a video file and the other should send a notification to the users.Everything works fine when I close my iPhone to the beacon which plays the audio file, but when I test the other beacon which sends notifications, the app sends 1 notification only and suddenly stops working. I assume that I am trying to display the same notification unlimited amount of times, but I do not know how to fix that problem. This is the error I get:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <Audio.DEViewController: 0x149f05190>.'
```

Please look at my code bellow:

```
 var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
 var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

 var avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
 var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "8492E75F-4FD6-469D-B132-043FE94921D8")!, identifier: "Estimotes")


let videos = [


19987: NSURL ( string: "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"),
3542: UIAlertController(title:"Permission Required", message:"Location services permission is required.", preferredStyle:.alert)

        ]
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {

let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }
if (knownBeacons.count > 0) {
let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon

if let url = self.videos[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] {

 let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
        }

        url.addAction(ok)
        self.present(url as UIViewController, animated:true){}


// only execute this code once, if avPlayer not created yet
if self.avPlayer == nil { 
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as! URL)
    self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
    self.present(self.avPlayerViewController,animated: true) { () -> Void in
    self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
}
}
```

Also how cn I enable sending a notification even when the user has closed the app. I have added the

```
     Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
```

in my

```
     info.plist
```

But still when I close the app and try to display the notification , nothing is happening.

```
    if let url = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor.intValue] {

            if (NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.lastNotificationTime > 10) {
                self.lastNotificationTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate


                let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
                }

                url.addAction(ok)
                self.present(url as UIViewController, animated:true){}
            }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code where you set the notification and send it to the user?

Comment: Sure, please look at the last paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot present a view controller more than once.  It is the same essential problem that I answered here: [How to play a video after iBeacon detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173613/how-to-play-a-video-after-ibeacon-detection/41174390#41174390)

To clarify, although the question mentions a "notification", the issue is really with an alert dialog.   (Notification on iOS typically has a more specific meaning where it refers to a `NSNotificaitonCenter` item that can show up on the lock screen.)

The alert dialog instance is constructed once when the class loads at the time `let videos` is initialized.  Then it is presented to the user inside the `unc locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion)` method, which gets called every second.

**You can't re-present the exact same instance of the alert dialog every second.  You can only present it once, otherwise you will get the error shown.**  You can show it again only after it is no longer displayed to the user.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I added a timer, you can check in my updated code, but the problem now is that every time I get the notification. The UIAlert action "OK" is re-presented and after every notification I get +1 OK and it is a bug because at some point I get 1 notification with 10 OK actions. How can I fix that?